# Twitter search API doesn't return tweets if name contains numbers

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am trying to get the JSON object which will contain tweets of a particular handle.

Here is the function I am using to send requests and store response in local storage:

```
function sendRequest(handle, noOfTweets, boolDisplay){
        $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:"+handle+"&rpp="+noOfTweets+"&callback=?", function(data) {
        if(boolDisplay){
            displayTweets(data);
        }
        localStorage.setItem("tweets"+handle, JSON.stringify(data));
      });
}
```

I am getting responses containing tweets of the user IF the user name doesn't contain numbers.
If the handle contains any numbers, then there are no tweets returned.

I have tried it by directly using address bar for the same requests.

eg:
(Following are handle names)

- ndtv works
- toi works
- pranavjain64 (my handle) *doesn't work*
- CNBCTV18news *doesn't work*

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: from the [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), there is no such field called `from:`, why are you using it?

Comment: was using the code from example here:
[link](http://boldr.net/faster-ajax-html5-localstorage)

Comment: you are using an example that has **more than 2 years**! the API changed a lot since then...

Comment: @balexandre, `from:` is not an parameter of request. Is an query search operator. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Comment: @AndrewD. thanks to point it out, didn't know that part :)

Comment: @balexandre Thanks for pointing out. What is a query search operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the status api rather than search here.

```
 function sendRequest(handle, noOfTweets, boolDisplay){
        $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="+ handle + "&count=" + noOfTweets + "&c
allback=?", function(data) {
        if(boolDisplay){
            displayTweets(data);
        }
        localStorage.setItem("tweets"+handle, JSON.stringify(data));
      });
  }
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Since is recommended but optional I believe. Also - This won't be a drop-in fix, as the returned data is in a different structure, but hopefully the change won't be too painful.

Comment: Actually, it should be since_id and max_id, but neither are required, so I removed them from my answer.

Comment: Thanks..
Will put in my code and check. Sorry for sounding lazy, but can you please tell in short the difference between search and status api?

Comment: There are a lot of differences, but generally: Search is for a set of recent tweets on a given topic, while the status interface will return a set of public tweets from specific user. Search has more limitations, the biggest being it only goes back about a week.

Comment: Hey, i tried using the status api, but am having trouble parsing its results.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle that illustrates your issue.